# gh-pages белый экран

Tags: javascript, github-pages

[Вот](https://github.com/salco2012/v-photo) мой репозиторий GitHub в ветке gh-pages. Сделал все как нужно и по инструкции. Добавил vue.config.js и deploy.sh. Но, при этом отображается белая страница. Если скачать локально, все отображается, а в гитхабе пустой экран. Подскажите в чем причина?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не получается загрузить проект на vue CLI 2 на GitHub Pages](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1300977/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-vue-cli-2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-github-pages)

Comment: Плодить вопросы об одном и том же - не только бессмысленно, но и вредно.